# JQueryMobile ID selector not picking up the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-mobile

Why is this selector not working?
I'm using the latest version of JQuery Mobile (1.0 b3) and jquery 1.6.2

selector

```
function updateStatusBar(statusMessage) {
    alert("Hello World!");
    $("#status-bar").html(statusMessage);
}
```

markup

```
...
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="<?php echo $data_theme; ?>">
    <div id="status-bar"></div>
</div>
...
```

and for testing purposes I have the function updateStatusBar being called from

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    updateStatusBar("Foo Bar");
});
```

However as it stands only the alert message is seen. The `innerHTML` of the div is not updated. Is this even a selector issue? I must mention that I have another function on the same page with the selectors `"[class*=ui-bar-], [class*=ui-body-], [class*=ui-btn-]"` and that works.. so i'm positive I have all the libraries included correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mobileinit` is for configuring options in jQuery Mobile, not for doing stuff when the document is ready. The DOM is not necessarily ready to use at this point.

You should use [`pageInit`](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) instead (or just change your "mobileinit" to "pageinit", this should do the same thing).

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

*(Edited to refer to `pageInit` as you should use that instead of `.ready()` in jQuery mobile as content gets loaded by AJAX after the DOM is ready)*

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood that from their documents. The other function is called `onclick` so that would make sense that it works.

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer as my original advice to use `.ready()` wasn't correct, apologies.